# How to get multiple fields returned in elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

How to get multiple fields returned that are unique using elasticsearch query?

All of my documents have duplicate `name` and `job` fields. I would like to use an es query to get all the unique values which include the name and job in the same response, so they are tied together.

```
[
{
    "name": "albert",
    "job": "teacher",
    "dob": "11/22/91"
},
{
    "name": "albert",
    "job": "teacher",
    "dob": "11/22/91"
},
{
    "name": "albert",
    "job": "teacher",
    "dob": "11/22/91"
},
{
    "name": "justin",
    "job": "engineer",
    "dob": "1/2/93"
},
{
    "name": "justin",
    "job": "engineer",
    "dob": "1/2/93"
},
{
    "name": "luffy",
    "job": "rubber man",
    "dob": "1/2/99"
}
]
```

Expected result in any format -> I was trying to use aggs but I only get one field

```
[
    {
        "name": "albert",
        "job": "teacher"
    },
    {
        "name": "justin",
        "job": "engineer"
    },
    {
        "name": "luffy",
        "job": "rubber man"
    },

]
```

This is what I tried so far

```
GET name.test.index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
      "name" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "name.keyword" }
      }
    }
}
```

using the above query gets me this which is good that its unique

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 95,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "name" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Justin",
          "doc_count" : 56
        },
        {
          "key" : "Luffy",
          "doc_count" : 31
        },
        {
          "key" : "Albert",
          "doc_count" : 8
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried doing nested aggregation but that did not work. Is there an alternative solution for getting multiple unique values or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a good start! There are a few ways to achieve what you want, each provides a different response format, so you can decide which one you prefer.

**The first option** is to leverage the [`top_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) sub-aggregation and return the two fields for each name bucket:

```
GET name.test.index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": [
              "name",
              "job"
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**The second option** is to use a [`script`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script) in your terms aggregation instead of a field to return a compound value:

```
GET name.test.index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "name": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc['name'].value + ' - ' + doc['job'].value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**The third option** is to use two levels of [field collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#_second_level_of_collapsing):

```
GET name.test.index/_search
{
  "collapse": {
    "field": "name",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "by_job",
      "collapse": {
        "field": "job"
      },
      "size": 1
    }
  }
}
```